# hadoop.hdfs_clusters.default.webhdfs_url Error in Hue

Tags: hadoop, hue

Can anyone help me I'm getting this error in hue.

```
Current value: http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1
Failed to create temporary file "/tmp/hue_config_validation.15785472045199379485"
```

FYI, I'm using Cloudera Manager 5.1.3 and Hue 3.6.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I solve my own problem. The cause of the error is NameNode in safe mode.

This command will make your Namenode leave safemode.

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

For more information why your NameNode get into safe mode.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Safemode

Comment: the problem still exist when i follow your step